# Selenium WebDriver: how to count number of DIV elements in a list

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to count the number of rows within a data grid on a webpage using Selenium.  Each row is represented by a div using the following structure (simplified for this post) :-

```
<div id="resultsGrid">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div/>
            <div>
                <div class="canvas">
                    <div data-bind="foreach: renderedRows">
                        <div>list item</div>
                        <div>list item</div>
                        <div>list item</div>
                        <div>list item</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From reading other similar posts I've tried using the following code and XPath to return the number of div's within the `<div data-bind="foreach: renderedRows">`

```
var rowCount = webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='usersResultsGrid']/div/div/div[2]/div/div")).Count;
```

Whenever I try this I just get a count of 1 returned, not the expected 4 (in this example).  Can anyone point in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Resolved.  The answer was to add an additional div to the xpath as in By.XPath("//*[@id='usersResultsGrid']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div").  My initial xpath was pointing to the div 'data-bind' element which of course only has a count of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. The answer was to add an additional div to the xpath as in By.XPath("//*[@id='usersResultsGrid']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div"). My initial xpath was pointing to the div 'data-bind' element which of course only has a count of 1, and I needed the list of div's below it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below any of the `xpath` which will identify all four elements.

```
//div[@id='resultsGrid']//div[@class='canvas']/div[@data-bind]/div
```

Or

```
//div[@id='resultsGrid']//div[@data-bind]/div
```

Effectively your code will be

```
var rowCount = webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='resultsGrid']//div[@class='canvas']/div[@data-bind]/div")).Count;
```

---

Comment: As above, rowCount returned is zero.  Tried both methods along with a wait statement to ensure it was loaded into the DOM.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Check DOM element must be inside an iframe?

Comment: There is no iframe.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of rows within the data grid using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  var rowCount = webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("div#resultsGrid div.canvas div[data-bind$='renderedRows'] > div")).Count;
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  var rowCount = webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='resultsGrid']//div[@class='canvas']/div[contains(@data-bind, 'renderedRows')]/div")).Count;
  ```

---

Ideally, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  var rowCount = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("div#resultsGrid div.canvas div[data-bind$='renderedRows'] > div")));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  var rowCount = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//div[@id='resultsGrid']//div[@class='canvas']/div[contains(@data-bind, 'renderedRows')]/div")));
  ```

Comment: Tried both methods and get rowCount = 0.  I put a check in front of the evaluation to ensure it has loaded in the DOM, even put a hard wait in there just to be totally sure, but still get a rowCount of 0.